# Help determining normalisation constant in SALC of methane

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, molecular-orbital-theory, orbitals, group-theory

We have been told that a symmetry adapted combination of four hydrogen orbitals is used to create localised hydrogen orbitals for methane. These orthonormal combinations are denoted ψa1, ψt’2, ψt’’2 and ψt’’’2.

It then asks to calculate the normalisation constant for the localised orbital Ψ = ψa1 – ψt’2 – ψt’’2 – ψt’’’2.

What I have done is reduce the symmetry representation of the 4 H s orbitals to Γ = A1 + T2. From here I have drawn an MO diagram and shown that there is overlap between the C 2s orbital and the A1 combination of H s orbitals, and also overlap between the C 2p orbitals and T2 combination of H s orbitals. So I am assuming that the combinations denoted above are these respective molecular orbitals. Therefore, the orbital for which I am asked to determine the normalisation constant is just the A1 MO subtracting the 3 T2 MOs.

From here I am stuck as to how to normalise this wavefunction. I know that N = 1/sqrt(Σci^2) but I cannot determine what the ci coefficients are?

Surely they aren't just the coefficients of ψa1, ψt’2, ψt’’2 and ψt’’’2? Which would give N = 1/2 - seems far too straightforward.

I know that for Ψ to be normalised we require the integral of its square to be equal to 1 which requires each of the components' square integrals be equal to 1/4. This would suggest the normalisation constant is sqrt(1/4) = 1/2?

Comment: Indeed, it is *that* straightforward. :-) By the way, the individual square integrals need not be all $1/4$. As long as they add up to $1$, that's fine.

Comment: Thank you. So just to clarify, the normalisation constant for Ψ = ψa1 – ψt’2 – ψt’’2 – ψt’’’2 is simply 1/2?

Comment: Yes, that's right. As long as the individual $\psi$'s are normalised, of course. But you said that already.